# Does @Html.Textarea sanitize input?

Tags: c#, validation, razor

I have a web form that allows you to enter user input into an @Html.Textarea.  If there is a form validation error, then the input is shown back in the text area.  If the form submits successfully, the user's input is sent to the database.

I've tried various things I can think of to do SQL injection, and it appears that Microsoft's built in functionality is catching it.  What should I be doing to sanitize this input?

I'm using the latest MVC Razor framework.  We are using strong types.  I've read about Html.Encode, but I think the Html.Textarea method is already doing this?  I have not implemented it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Razor part does not implement any of this checking (since it has no way of knowing what you consider to be valid input). However the database layer you are using in MVC almost certainly deals with injection attacks.

Comment: Ok, if validation is happening at a data layer, then any thoughts on cross site scripting attacks?  Should I be doing anything to prevent that?

Comment: Yes, you should be using something like https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer to prevent XSS